# InvalidCastException using System.Linq.Expressions on Compact Framework

Tags: c#, .net, linq, compact-framework

I am using a `System.Linq.Expressions` implementation from the db4o project. The code runs on Windows Mobile 6 on the .Net Compact Framework 3.5. It is mentioned [here](http://evain.net/blog/articles/2008/09/22/linq-expression-trees-on-the-compact-framework/) and the source is [here](https://source.db4o.com/db4o/trunk/db4o.net/Libs/compact-3.5/System.Linq.Expressions/). I have been using this for a while and it has mostly run very well. However I now encounter an `InvalidCastException` when trying to convert `Func` delegates that return a reference type to expression trees. The `InvalidCastException` is caused by what I think is a bug in the .Net Compact Framework. I have a second code sample further down that details this bug.

**Example of InvalidCastException using System.Linq.Expressions**

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // throws InvalidCastException
        Expression<Func<object>> expr = () => new object();
    }
}
```

This exception prevents me from writing a LINQ to SQL like [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548743%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that projects into an anonymous type.

This is the complete stack trace for the exception, as you can see there is no additional information there:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  Message="InvalidCastException"
  StackTrace:
    at ConsoleTest.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I looked at the generated CIL (see below) using ILDASM and it turns out the invalid cast is a cast from `MethodBase` to `ConstructorInfo`. This cast is necessary because a `NewExpression` is generated in the body of the lambda by calling [one of the overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.new%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) of `Expression.New` with an argument of type `ConstructorInfo`. The reason this does not happen for value types is because then [the overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352804%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) with a single argument of type `Type` is used. (Calling one of the overloads with a `ConstructorInfo` argument from code in my application works fine by the way, the problem only occurs when the expression tree is built by code generated by the compiler.)

Since the problem occurs with the `Expression.New` overloads with an argument of type `ConstructorInfo` I tried changing those methods and have them accept an argument of `MethodBase` or even `object` instead of `ConstructorInfo`. But this gives a compilation error:

> Missing compiler required member
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New'

Apparently (and justifiably) the compiler is very picky about the signature of the methods.

**Example of bug in .Net Compact Framework**

The following code gives the same invalid cast but without using the custom `System.Linq.Expressions` (this code runs fine on .Net 3.5 but fails on .Net Compact Framework 3.5):

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Get method handle of parameterless constructor
        Type type = typeof(object);
        ConstructorInfo constructorInfo0 = type.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
        RuntimeMethodHandle runtimeMethodHandle = constructorInfo0.MethodHandle;

        // Get method from method handle
        MethodBase methodBase =
            MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(runtimeMethodHandle);

        // Casting back to ConstructorInfo throws InvalidCastException on .Net CF
        ConstructorInfo constructorInfo1 = (ConstructorInfo)methodBase;
    }
}
```

My questions (yes, I am getting there, thank you for reading this far).

- Can I do anything to make the first code sample work?
- More generally can I do anything to get expression trees from the compiler where the body has `NewExpressions` which are created by one of the `New` overloads with a `ConstructorInfo` argument?
- Out of interest, is the `InvalidCastException` in the second code sample a bug in the .Net Compact Framework or is that code trying to do something that is not supported on .Net CF?

For what it's worth, this is what ILDASM gives for the `Main` method in the first code sample:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       40 (0x28)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<class [System.Core]System.Func`1<object>> expr)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldtoken    method instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Reflection.MethodBase [mscorlib]System.Reflection.MethodBase::GetMethodFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeMethodHandle)
  IL_000b:  castclass  [mscorlib]System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo
  IL_0010:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0011:  newarr     [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression
  IL_0016:  call       class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression::New(class [mscorlib]System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo,
                                                                                                                                                             class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression[])
  IL_001b:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_001c:  newarr     [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression
  IL_0021:  call       class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<!!0> [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression::Lambda<class [System.Core]System.Func`1<object>>(class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression,
                                                                                                                                                                                                              class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression[])
  IL_0026:  stloc.0
  IL_0027:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Comment: why did you add the *mono* tag?

Comment: @knocte: Because the source db4o used for System.Linq.Expressions is from the Mono project.

Comment: what do you mean? db4o is not hosted in mono repositories and has never been

Comment: @knocte: In the first link I have in my post, JB Evain writes: "What those fine folks did, was simply to take Mono's implementation of this namespace.", where "those fine folks" are db4o and "this namespace" is `System.Linq.Expressions`. I appreciate that my question may not be relevant to people that are just interested in Mono. But it may very well be that a solution to my problem may come from Mono (by adding a part of Mono or even replacing a part of .Net CF by a part of Mono). That is why I added the Mono tag.

Comment: I think that the origin of db4o's code is irrelevant to your issue

Comment: It's not irrelevant if the issue he's seeing is because of a bug in the `System.Linq.Expressions` code he's using, which came from Mono.  I'm not saying that's where the problem lies, but if it does, then it's highly relevant.